# GET data is not accessible after redirecting a page in cakephp form

Tags: cakephp, redirect, parameters, get

I am new to cakephp and trying to save a data. Basically I am saving data in a form where a security key is passed in the url. This key is passed to the form and if the form successfully submitted it is redirected to a the same page with the key. If the two keys matched( key used in redirect and the `POS`T key), show the form again otherwise redirect to another error page.

```
function add($key=""){

    $this->key = $key;
    if(empty($this->data)){
        //check key for first time page load
        if ($key != 'mykey') {
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
            exit();
        } else {
            $this->set("key", $this->key);
        }

    }
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        //Check Key after form submission
        if($this->data["GalLocations"]["key"] != $this->key){
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
            exit();
        } else {
            $this->set("key", $this->key);

            $this->GalLocation->create();
            if($this->GalLocation->save($this->data)){
                $this->Session->setFlash("Location added successfully");    
                $this->redirect(array("controller" => "gal_locations", "action" => "add", "mykey"));
                exit();
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

But the line `if($this->data["GalLocations"]["key"] != $this->key)` always fails, ie `$this->key` is empty ! Whats wrong ? why it is empty always ?

NB: I am redirecting because I need to hide the key from the URL after submitting the page.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I'm following the logic, but it may not matter.  Just to confirm, what does the URL look like at each step?

Comment: URL : `http://localhost/main/gal_locations/add/mykey`

Comment: can you paste the part where you create the form, in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Use $key, you cannot assign value to $this->key

```
Remove $this->key = $key;
if($this->data["GalLocations"]["key"] != $key)
```

Comment: $this->redirect(array("controller" => "gal_locations", "action" => "add/$key")); and remove exit after redirect line

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'gal_locations', 'action' => 'add', $key));`?